Tailwind CSS not working with Vite.js in a Node.js application
I'm trying to integrate Tailwind CSS into a Vite.js-powered Node.js application, but I'm having trouble getting the styles to apply correctly. I've followed the official Tailwind CSS and Vite.js integration guides, but the Tailwind utility classes are not being applied to my Vue.js components.
My Setup:

Node.js version: v16.x
Vite.js version: 4.x
Tailwind CSS version: 3.x

My Configuration:
tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  purge: ["./src/"],
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: true,
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};


vite.config.js:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      css: {
        additionalData: `@import "./src/assets/style.css";`,
      },
    },
  },
});


style.css (located in src/assets):
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


What I've Tried:
Verified the file paths and configurations in the tailwind.config.js and vite.config.js files.
Checked the style.css file to ensure the Tailwind CSS directives are correctly imported.
Ran the Vite.js development server and inspected the browser's developer tools to see if the CSS is being loaded properly.
Tried running the Tailwind CLI directly to generate the CSS output.
Checked for any Vue.js-specific Tailwind CSS configuration options that might be needed.
Inspected the generated CSS files in the dist folder after running npm run build.
Expected Behavior:
The Tailwind CSS utility classes should be correctly applied to my Vue.js components, allowing me to use Tailwind's styling capabilities in my application.
Actual Behavior:
The Tailwind CSS styles are not being applied to the components, and the UI appears unstyled.
Error Messages or Logs:
I don't see any obvious error messages or logs related to the Tailwind CSS integration. The application runs without any apparent issues, but the Tailwind styles are simply not being applied.
Additional Context:
I'm using a Node.js backend with a Vue.js frontend, and I'm trying to integrate Tailwind CSS into the entire application. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Remove purge: ["./src/"] as it's obsolete, and there shouldn't be a mention of it in latest documentation for integrating tailwind and vite.  I tested in local dev and just adding this option broke tailwind classes for me, so this may be your problem.

Awesome, works, thanks! So "content" instead should do the optimisation?

I recommend following the official guide: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite
